# How to switch between HTML Select options with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML select with 3 options as following -

```
<select id="list">
    <option value="environment" selected>Environment Facing (default)</option>
    <option value="user">User Facing</option>
    <option value="member">Member Facing</option>
</select>
```

what I want to do is to toggle between these values with a button. is that possible? How can I toggle like if first option is selected and if I click button second option get selected and if second is selected after clicking again third gets selected. is there any way I can do it.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the `selectedIndex` of the `select`, wrapping around when you get to the end.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let selected = list.selectedIndex;
  selected = (selected + 1) % list.length;
  list.selectedIndex = selected;
});

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  console.log(`Selected = ${list.value}`);
});
```

```html
<select id="list">
  <option value="environment" selected>Environment Facing (default)</option>
  <option value="user">User Facing</option>
  <option value="member">Member Facing</option>
</select>

<button id="button" type="button">Toggle</button>

<button id="show" type="button">Show selected</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget that the default type for `button` is `submit`. As long as you're not in a `form` context this is not damaging, yet you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: Yes thanks but it's not updating the selected. it's just changing the option. I mean the selected state is not changing

Comment: It's changing the selected. I added another button to show the current selected value.

Comment: He's expecting the attribute to switch to the selected option, but that does never happen.

Comment: The `selected` attribute is just the initial default, not the current state.

Comment: Thank You but actually I have more code that executes whenever we click on any option that code executes when I click on any option (a onchange event fires when I click on any option) that on change event is not getting fired when I try it with button.

Comment: `onchange` only fires when an input is changed by the user, not by code.

Comment: @LuckChhipa By the looks of your comments you are falling victim to a whole number of misconceptions about how these input elements work in the web. I recommend you take your time to take a deep dive into how attributes like `value`,  `checked`, `selected` work (all initial values only!), and what triggers things like `input` or `change` events (which only user interaction does).

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be getting the available values into an array, and finding the currently selected value's index in that array, increase it by one and see if you get a value. If you get `undefined` (which is what you get if you try to access an array element at a non-existing index), you instead go with the arrays's first element.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const values = [...list.options].map(({value}) => value);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const currentValue = list.value;
  list.value = values[values.indexOf(currentValue)+1] ?? values[0];
});
```

```html
<select id="list">
  <option value="environment" selected>Environment Facing (default)</option>
  <option value="user">User Facing</option>
  <option value="member">Member Facing</option>
</select>

<button id="button" type="button">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: but it's not changing the selected state of values. I need to change the selected state as well. I mean toggling should happen like we are clicking on each option.

Comment: The `selected` attribute **never** changes, doesn't matter if you change the value programmatically or if the user does it by interacting with the element. The only purpose of the `selected` attribute is to tell the `select` element which value should *initially* be selected and displayed. So no matter how and what option you select after the initial rendering of the  `select`, the attribute `selected` will remain on the first option in your example.